# SPItemEventReceiver ItemAdding - Differentiate between a file and a folder

Tags: 2007, development, document-library, event-handlers

I've setup a custom event receiver.  The purpose of my event receiver is to stop people from uploading any file type except PDF's.  Right now my code looks like this:

```
            if (properties.AfterUrl.Substring(properties.AfterUrl.Length-4).ToLower() != ".pdf")
            {
                properties.Cancel = true;
                properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
                properties.ErrorMessage = "Adding non PDF files is not allowed.";
            }
```

The problem is that this prevents people from adding folders, unless you make all your folder names end with .pdf :).  I've considered the option of putting a check to see if the item being added contains a period, like `properties.AfterUrl.Contains(".")`, however this would allow tricky people to upload files that have no extension and would disallow folder names with periods.

I did a comparison of SPItemEventProperties between WSS3 and 2010 and found that they added a property called FileSystemObjectTypePropertyName, my guess is that in 2010 this property fills the roll.  For the time being though I am stuck with WSS3.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to differentiate by knowing Content Type of the item being added. You can get Content Type by accessing properties.AfterProperties["ContentTypeId"]

As documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543822.aspx), Document Content Type ID starts with 0x0101 vs Folder's content type id - 0x0120

So your code may look like:

> SPContentTypeId itemContentType = new SPContentTypeId(properties.AfterProperties["ContentTypeId"]);
>
> SPContentTypeId folderContentType =  SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Folder;
>
> if (!itemContentType.IsChildOf(folderContentType))
>
> {
>
> // this should be a document not a folder
>
> }

Comment: ContentType is not present. ContenTypeId is present when I use the web interface (properties.AfterProperties["ContentTypeId"]) but not when I use the Windows Explorer interface.  ContentTypeId appears to be a guid.

Comment: Just saw your update.  I do think that throught the web interface this would solve the issue, now I'm just worried about people going through Explorer view.

Comment: can you share the examples of value you are getting when usig web and explorer interface?

Comment: When adding a folder using Explorer view there are no after properties (which is odd). When adding a file through explorer view I have "vti_filesize", which seems to equal zero even if the file has size, and "vti_parserversion" which is "12.0.0.6562".

Comment: see my update again.. I am not sure about the behavior using Explorer.. I am curious to know if sharepoint would cancel the action if it is not allowed!

Comment: Curious if SharePoint will cancel the uploading of a file through explorer view if I say properties.Cancel=true?  If thats your question then the answer is yes, it does cancel it (already tested that part).

Comment: good to know that.. vti_filesize will be null or empty for folders. that way you can differentiate...

Answer (score 6):

With SP2010, You can use *ItemAdded* with *Synchronization* (instead of *ItemAdding*) to perform some operations
after the item is created but before it is presented to the user.
Then you can use `if(properties.ListItem.File!=null)`to determine if listitem has file associated with it.

To make *ItemAdded* synchronous, you need to set the *Synchronization* property either through the 
*SPEventReceiverDefinition* object model if you are registering your events programmatically or
by creating below node in your  XML that sets the value to Synchronous or Asynchronous.

```
<Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately properties.ListItem is always null during the ItemAdding event because the ListItem does not exist yet.

Comment: @Patricker,See my Edit above

Comment: This looks like a great option.  When we upgrade to 2010 I'll switch my code to work this way.

Answer (score 1):

Old Post - but I've got this working in SP2010 ItemAdding and believe you almost had the answer in one of your comments:

> When adding a folder using Explorer view there are no after properties (which is odd). When adding a file through explorer view I have "vti_filesize", which seems to equal zero even if the file has size, and "vti_parserversion" which is "12.0.0.6562".  – Peter Nov 16 '11 at 17:38

The afterProperty "vti_filesize" is *always null* when dealing with folders. The "vti_filesize" is *always non-null* when dealing with documents. So simply check for "vti_filesize" to be null and you know it's a folder.

Comment: Jon, we found that with SP2010 that what you are saying is the case, but that in SP2007 both files and folders showed a zero file size in Explorer view.  Sp2007 at the time was what we were working with.

Comment: I figured that would be the case in Explorer View itself. Odd how it's non-null in the afterProperties though (from your observation). I'm only testing on SP2010, so hopefully this helps somebody on the newer platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add pdf to the blocked file list:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262496.aspx

Comment: Two issues with this approach.  One, we dont want to block pdf, we want to block everything BUT pdf.  Two, this setting is at the  Web application level.  We have a ton of sites with lists where we put no restrictions on the file type.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, check if `properties.BeforeUrl` contains a dot (dots are not allowed in folder names):

```
string url = properties.BeforeUrl;
if (url .Contains(".")) //it is a file * not a folder
{
   //To do
}
```